# Lifetime of parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, closures, lifetime

Excerpt from section 7.1 of "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 4th Edition":

> Note that these **parameter variables** are defined only while the function is being executed; they **do not persist once the function returns**.

Is that really true? Does that mean I have to save some parameters to local variables if I intend to use them from within nested functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close over parameters just as with any other local variable, like so:

```
function test(v1) {
    return function() {
        alert(v1);
    }
}

var f = test("hello");
f();
```

This is only because the returned function closes over the variables in its lexical scope. In the normal case, yes, it's true that parameters are local to a function and do not persist once the function returns.